# can we pass parameters in view of a table in SQL?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is there any way to pass parameters to a view in postgresql? or any alternative of passing parameter from spring jpa native query

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ways to pass params to a query in JPA

1. Using index, here spring data will pass method parameters to the query in the same order they appear in the method declaration:

   ```
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
   findById(Integer id);
   ```
2. By Names using `@Param` annotation in the method declaration to match parameters defined

   ```
   @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
   findById(@Param("id")Integer id);
   ```

Comment: I am asking  to pass parameters in views.